# Как правильно использовать requestAnimationFrame()

Tags: javascript

Гугл советует использовать `requestAnimationFrame()` для внесения визуальных изменений. Допустим, у меня есть следующий код:

```
function reshowTickets() {
    let tickets = document.getElementById('tickets-holder').children;

    for(let i = 0; i < tickets.length; i++) {
        let ticket = $(tickets[i]);

        ticket.css({'transition': 'all .3s ease', 'opacity': '0', 'transform': 'scale(.85)'});
        setTimeout(() => ticket.remove(), 300);
    }
}
```

Функция поочерёдно убирает элементы DOM придавая перед удалением со страницы красивую анимацию. Но как мне переписать эту функцию так, чтобы она использовала `requestAnimationFrame()`? И будет ли оно работать так, как работает сейчас?

Comment: Почитай https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame